# Useful command line tools in .NET Framework/Windows SDK(svcutil.exe, xsd.exe... etc)

Tags: .net, command-line, winapi

As I learn more and more about SV2010 and .NET Framework/Windows SDK, I have the sensation that there are many features that I don't know, and I'm pretty sure that I will not know about them when I need it, but a week later.

For example: XSD tool let me generate a class from a XML Document, WcfTestClient.exe let me test a WCF service, WcfSvcHost.exe let me host a wcf service for testing pourposes, svcutil.exe let me generate code from a wcf service... etc

What are the most useful of them? Any of them have saved you a lot of time?

Are there any book, blog or Document that could explain me all that features and tools before it is too late. I only need a quick reference, I only need to know that that kind of tools exists, so Then the time comes, I will search more specifyc documentacion in msdn.

Comment: Sorry for being a pedant, but most of them are actually part of .NET Framework/Windows SDK, not Visual Studio. And there is even a dedicated page that lists all of them http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9kh6s92.aspx but I'm sure you're aware of it.

Comment: Thanks for clarify it +1.I've edit the title and the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found an interesting link about this topic just 5 minutes ago: "[Link](http://www.devcurry.com/2011/02/important-net-framework-40-command-line.html)"